# use SQLite in windows CE wrote by C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-ce

I made an app for my PDA and use SQLite as database. I did it as below:

1. Added System.Data.SQLite.dll to my REFERENCE
2. Added SQLite.Interop.066.DLL , SQLite.Interop.066.exp , SQLite.Interop.066.lib to solution
3. Called ref with using System.Data.SQLite;

and my connection string and command string is:

```
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BSTDB.sqlite;Version=3");
    string sqlwrite = "INSERT INTO RR (Serial) VALUES('"+cBox1.Text+"')";
    SQLiteCommand cmdwrite = new SQLiteCommand(sqlwrite, con);
    con.Open();
    cmdwrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

But when I start program, this error occurs:

> SQLite error no such table:

Can anyone guide me what is my problem?

Meanwhile, this app is working correct on Windows 7 now.

This is my codes in dotnetfx4.5:

```
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BSTDB.sqlite;Version=3;");
    string sqlwrite = "INSERT INTO SetSerial (Serial,Tarikh,OpName) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    SQLiteCommand cmdwrite = new SQLiteCommand(sqlwrite, con);
    cmdwrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", s1);
    cmdwrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tarikh", s2);
    cmdwrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpName", s3);
    con.Open();
    cmdwrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

and my apps working correct

Comment: Do you have a `RR` table in your database?

Comment: And always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: What schema name does it have?

Comment: doesn't this problem back to my references?

Comment: what's your mean from "What schema name it have"? it back to what?

Comment: Is your table in the `master` database, or did you create another? According to the Connection String you provided, you're most likely hitting the `master` database.

Comment: Where, exactly, is this database?  Locally on the device?  If so where's you fully-qualified path?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in yout query (despite of it non-parametrization) is that you are using schema name for the table. Try to set the correct schema, like this:

```
string sqlwrite = "INSERT INTO [BSTDB].[sqlite].[RR] (Serial) VALUES('"+cBox1.Text+"')";
```

Or, if you want to pass by the owner's name:

```
string sqlwrite = "INSERT INTO [BSTDB]..[RR] (Serial) VALUES('"+cBox1.Text+"')";
```

Comment: let me try your suggestion

Comment: which is correct:     >string sqlwrite = "INSERT INTO [BSTDB.sqlite].[RR] (Serial) VALUES('" + cBox1.Text + "')"; or string sqlwrite = "INSERT INTO BSTDB.sqlite RR (Serial) VALUES('" + cBox1.Text + "')";?

Comment: I think I use this schema incorrectly. **INSERT INTO BSTDB.sqlite RR(Serial) VALUES('" + cBox1.Text + "')** or _INSERT INTO BSTDB.sqlite.RR(Serial) VALUES('" + cBox1.Text + "')_ what is true string?

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi BSTDB.sqlite.RR

Comment: I tried this but error still there. I think error back to my Database or Reference library.

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi May be you are connecting to the wrong database, and there is no such table?